# mysql connection taking too long after a few connections

Tags: php, mysql, centos

i have Mysql 5.7 on Centos 7 here is my.cnf:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

key_buffer_size = 512M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 1024M
tmp_table_size = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
##innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 10M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
max_connections = 250
sort_buffer_size = 64M

long_query_time = 5
slow_query_log = 1
skip-name-resolve
```

As you can see i have **skip-name-resolve** anyway i made test.php:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0;$i<1000;$i++) {
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    $conn = new \mysqli("xx.xx.xx.xxx","xxxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxx");
    $t2 = microtime(true);
    echo "connection: ". floatval($t2 - $t1). PHP_EOL;

    $t3 = microtime(true);
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT 1");
    $t4 = microtime(true);
    echo "query: ".$i.") ". floatval($t4-$t3) . PHP_EOL;
    $conn->close();
}
```

when i run this test.php after 65th loop i see connection duration is increasing to 1 second even 3 second here is the sample output:

```
...
...
query: 62) 0.0028440952301025
connection: 0.0020878314971924
query: 63) 0.002816915512085
connection: 0.002126932144165
query: 64) 0.002856969833374
connection: 1.0042409896851
query: 65) 0.013001918792725
connection: 1.0027761459351
query: 66) 0.01302695274353
connection: 1.002720117569
query: 67) 0.012753009796143
connection: 1.003103017807
query: 68) 0.012816905975342
connection: 1.0031731128693
query: 69) 0.012447118759155
connection: 1.003485918045
query: 70) 0.012918949127197
...
...
```

Every time i ran this test.php result was same always increasing the connection time to unacceptable times after 65th loop. i am realy confused. Anyone has anyidea?

Best regards.

Comment: seems like its limitting with something, i am not an expert but maybe its about with centos or mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem it was nothing with about mysql server itself. The problem was the hostname of centos7, given hostnames were not real so OS was trying to resolve them and taking too long there were two solition:

1) setting them with localhost with

```
hostnamectl --transient set-hostname "localhost"
```

2) redirct your fake hostname to localhost, lets assume ***mysql-server1.mydomain.com*** is hostname of the server

```
echo 127.0.0.1 mysql-server1.mydomain.com > /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create so many connections, but just one:

```
$conn = new mysqli("xx.xx.xx.xxx","xxxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxx");

for ($i = 0;$i<1000;$i++) {
    $t1 = microtime(true);

    $t2 = microtime(true);
    echo "connection: ". floatval($t2 - $t1). PHP_EOL;

    $t3 = microtime(true);
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT 1");
    $t4 = microtime(true);
    echo "query: ".$i.") ". floatval($t4-$t3) . PHP_EOL;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: i know i dont need new connections but i simulate my http API acctualy i have an http API if you make GET request to it it connects to DB and insert a new row thats all but i made a load test to it and i saw its the connection taking too time after some requests

Comment: try to set `$conn = null;` right after `$conn->close();` to force php free the variable.

Comment: i did and its same result , realy strange its getting slow after with 65th loop at every try :) i think its related with server setup or something new with mysql 5.7

Comment: try to set `$query = null;` either when connection closed

Comment: same :(, this time it was not the 65th loop maybe its about with my client server is there limit or something to open socket per second?